# Simple modrewrite to remove particular part of path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a modrewrite rule that will change:

`/blah/correct/xyz.htm`

to

`/correct/xyz.htm`

There is not always `/blah` but when it's there, it always appears at the beginning of the URL. The URL can be any length, with numerous sub-paths. It could even be `/blah/myfile.htm` (which should just rewrite to `/myfile.htm`).

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (?:^|/)blah(/.+)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

This will internally forward `/blah/foo` to `/foo` or `/blah/correct/foo` to `/correct/foo`. If you want external rewrite then use:

```
RewriteRule (?:^|/)blah(/.+)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```